# Get list from string using Regex Matches[C#]

Tags: c#

How to get List of Dates that were inside some string? How to use Regex here?

Example: "Lorem aaaa 12.01.2019 ffffffffdddddd hhhhhh 14.01.2019 nnnnnn ggg 15.01.2019 cxcccc ...."

Second question: How to learn to use Regex? Could you advise some links?

Comment: What constitutes a valid date? Is 15 Jan 2019 a valid date? Should it be matched in the string?

Comment: https://regexr.com is awesome ^^

Comment: The real question is what delimits each group?   Looks like each group starts with " "Lorem aaaa".  Is this fixed width columns or is there a separator? Did you combine rows together?  It is easier to parse before you combine rows.

Comment: @mjwills no only digits))

Comment: @jdweng, Hi )) That's just example man, in real string will be more than 1000 words, I need just get all dates from string line.

Comment: I know.  I just think the dates by themselves is not the whole issue.  Usually problems like this require getting more than just the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var list = Regex.Matches("Lorem aaaa 12.01.2019 ffffffffdddddd hhhhhh 14.01.2019 nnnnnn ggg 15.01.2019 cxcccc ....", @"\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}");`

Also I advise you use this extesion in visual studio, very handy tool.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasAndersen.RegularExpressionTesterExtension

Answer (score 1):

You need to first write a pattern for matching your dates from your provided string.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> dates = new List<string>();

        string pattern = @"\b\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\b";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

        var sentence = "Lorem aaaa 12.01.2019 ffffffffdddddd hhhhhh 14.01.2019 nnnnnn ggg 15.01.2019 cxcccc ....";

        var matches = rgx.Matches(sentence);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

The below are some links that you can learn to build your own regex.

- [regexone](https://regexone.com/)
- [regexr](https://regexr.com/)